# How to set optional arguments to positional arguments in Python's Argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code:

```py
# Get parsed arguments
args = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=Messages().Get(112))

# Get the arguments for sinit
args.add_argument('init', help=Messages().Get(100), action="store_true")
args.add_argument('--url', default=None, help=Messages().Get(101))

# Get the arguments for schema import
args.add_argument('schema-import', help=Messages().Get(104), action="store_true")
args.add_argument('--file', default=None, help=Messages().Get(104))
```

The `--url` argument should only be used with `init`. For example: `script.py schema-import --url` should *not* be accepted but `script.py schema-import --file` should.

How to set arguments as child arguments?

Comment: I guess you want to have [sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands).

Comment: I do this in application logic. check if args.schema-import and args.--url and if both then print("some error") and sys.exit(0). Find it more transparent. Not sure how it works with sub-commands

Comment: A `store_true` action doesn't take any arguments.  That means you can't supply 'init' or 'schema-import'.  Their values will be `True` regardless of your inputs.  Test your code without worrying about the coo-occurrence and print the resulting Namespace.

Comment: Do you even need a '--init' argument?  Just test `url' for a non-default value.  Same of `--file`.

Comment: @Neil that’s it. If you add it as an answer I’ll check it as answered (for the points) 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned there might be a way to do this with argparse, I'm not sure, but in any event I find it more transparent to explicitly handle argument dependencies in application logic. This should achieve what I think you want:

```
import argparse
import sys

args = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="please only use the '--url' argument if you also use the 'init' argument")
# Going to use aliases here it's more conventional. So user can use, eg,
# -i or --init for the first argument.

args.add_argument('-i', '--init', help='init help', action="store_true")
args.add_argument('-u', '--url', default=None, help='init help')

args.add_argument('-s', '--schema-import', help='schema-import help', action="store_true")
args.add_argument('-f', '--file', help='file help')


def main():
    arguments = args.parse_args()

    if arguments.url and not arguments.init:
        # You can log an output or raise an exception if you want
        # But most likely a print statment is most appropriate
        # Since you are interacting with the CLI.
        print("You can only use the URL option with init. Exiting")
        sys.exit(0)

    print("gaurd clauses passed. Here is my code...")
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Test results (my file called temp.py):

```
$python temp.py -u https://www.google.com
You can only use the URL option with init. Exiting
$

$python temp.py -i -u https://www.google.com
Gaurd clauses passed. Here is my code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with doing all the logic when you can let `argparse` do all the work for you?

Simply use [`Sub-commands`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) to define different "branches" of execution:

```py
args = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=Messages().Get(112))
subparsers = args.add_subparsers()

parser_init = subparsers.add_parser('init', help=Messages().Get(100))
parser_init.add_argument('--url', default=None, help=Messages().Get(101))

parser_schema = subparsers.add_parser('schema-import', help=Messages().Get(104))
parser_schema.add_argument('--file', default=None, help=Messages().Get(104))
```

And this will give you what you want without any logic added:

```py
>>> print(args.parse_args(['schema-import', '--url', "some.url"]))
usage: args.py [-h] {init,schema-import} ...
args.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --url some.url
>>> print(args.parse_args(['schema-import', '--file', "some.file"]))
Namespace(file='some.file')
```